# Use TCP socket to 'register' clients for UDP connection?

Tags: c++, networking, tcp, udp, boost-asio

I am trying to build a small online game (for the sake of learning) where clients join into the game, play, and leave as they will.

I am thinking of using a TCP socket to handle clients joining and leaving the game and subscribing to a UDP connection on the same socket.

Is this practice used or correct? I am writing this code in c++ with Boost.asio.

Comment: Define "subscribing to a UDP connection on the same socket".

Comment: So the client establishes a TCP connection on the socket, then the server adds them to the game, and begins communicating the game state with that client over UDP (on the same socket unique to the client)

Comment: Do you mean on the same *port number*? You can't use a TCP socket for UDP. And there is no such thing as a 'UDP connection' either.

Comment: Oops, yes that is what I mean

Comment: Well you can certainly do that, but do you need to? The first UDP message from a client must consistute a join, by definition, and if you don't hear from him for a while or receive a 'leave' message over UDP that's a leave. To get a foolproof 'leave' via TCP you would have to keep that connection open until the client closed it, which could be problematic in itself, and consumes resources.

Comment: So TCP isn't necessary to ensure a reliable registration process for clients?

Comment: It's necessary for registration, but I don't see that it's necessarily required for anything mentioned in the body of your question.

Comment: I didn't mean registration in a technical manner... I simply meant: if a player wants to join into a game, it's not necessary for me to establish an open connection with them over TCP to ensure they are in fact in the game? But, I think I understand that an initial UDP packet from a client would be enough to initiate a new player

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cant figure out why you need UDP at all? Is the game latency-critical? What are requirements?

For education purpose i'd prefer to stick with TCP and implement somewhat working. Then depending on problems/requirements modify it.

Answer (score -3):

I think you had better use an UDP socket to handle client joining and a TCP connection to deal with the game and subscribing.

Comment: The UDP can handle client joining efficiently. And TCP connectin is needed for subscribing. You can't do efficient subscribing with UDP.

Comment: So why use the TCP connection 'to deal with the game'? And what is the basis for your assertions? And why doesn't all this appear in your answer.

Comment: Generally game client uses sbucribing to receive server from game server.

Comment: So you say. Evidence? What does 'receive server from game server' mean?

Comment: receive "data". Sorry for the typo